# How to build a string with quotes?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I know that this type of question may already exist on the site, but none of the solutions provided helped me.

I want to build a dynamic ActionResult in MVC. I use the following class:

```
public class MyMenu
{
public string Action {get;set;}
public string Controller {get; set;}
public string Area {get;set;}
}
```

the action is:

```
public ActionResult OpenView(string btn)
{
var model=_repository.MyMenu.Get(btn);
area="new {Area=" + "\"" + model.Area + "\"}"; 

return RedirectToAction(model.Action, model.Controller,area);
}
```

In order for my action to work properly the area must be exactly like:

```
 area= new {Area="Home"}
```

the model return the area like this:
model.Area = Home

Can you, please, give me a solution?

**Edit:**

I need to bring some more info:

Your suggestion to use this :

**var area = string.Format("new {{Area=\"{0}\"}}", model.Area);**

is not working because this line:

**return RedirectToAction(model.Action, model.Controller,area);**

see the area like new {Area=\"Home\"}, and due to that I get an page not found (error 404).

If I write the area to Debug, yes I receive what I expect, but in my action is not working.

Do you have some other ideas?

**Edit 2:**

My issues was not related with building a string (which I was expecting). Base on all trials which I made, I reach the conclusion that I need to use If/elseIf statement or a switch to provide the area.

I am sure that must be a way to concatenate somehow the strings and quotes inside of an action, when I will found it I will post it here.

```
**Edit 3:**
```

I found the answer to my problem, which is :

```
 return RedirectToAction(model.Action, model.Controller, new RouteValueDictionary(new { Area = model.Area }));
```

I realize now,that my question was not the correct one, a good question in my case could be: **How to pass the Area like RootValue!!!.** 
I do not know if is ok for me to change the question, or ...

Comment: Eh, *formatting*? Something like `area = String.Format("new Area {\"{0}\"}", model.Area);`

Comment: Is not working, I got this error "Input string was not in a correct format."

Comment: @DmitryBychenko So you're saying move the `{` from before `Area=` to after it and remove the equal sign?

Comment: @juharr: take the string you want to have: `area= new {Area="Home"}`, escape `"` to `\"`, change value (i.e. `Home` to {0}) and you'll get the string `"area= new {Area=\"{0}\"}"`; then wrap into formatting: `String area = "area= new {Area=\"{0}\"}";`.

Comment: Have you tried using the literal notation on the string,  @"new {Area=""" + model.area + @"""}";

Comment: not giving the expected result

Comment: It might not be necessarily your question but isn't the third parameter supposed to be an object (routeValues) ?  .... area = new {Area=model.Area} ...

Comment: @DmitryBychenko I understand how to delimit a double quote.  I'm saying your exmaple is different from what the OP says they want.  And technically string concatenation should work just as well as using `string.Format`.

Answer (score 3):

To escape braces in when using `string.Format` you need to use `{{` and `}}`, instead.

```
area = String.Format("new {{ Area = \"{0}\" }}", model.Area);
```

The result of `String.Format("new {{ Area = \"{0}\" }}", "Home");` is  `new { Area = "Home" }`

**Edit**

Please try this code:

```
return RedirectToAction(model.Action, model.Controller, new { Area = model.Area });
```

Comment: the result is area=new {Area=\"Home\"}, which is not ok.

Comment: I believe you are confusing with what the debugger shows. Is that possible?

Comment: The code in my answer is to get the string you wanted. Now, going back to the fact it doesn't work, I stand with what @Sam.C said, the third parameter is supposed to be an object (routeValues). Are you sure you can use `return RedirectToAction(model.Action, model.Controller,"hardcode any string you want");` and it will work?

Comment: Personally I don't see a valid reason to bring `string.Format` into this.

Comment: @juharr, he needs to build a string with dynamic parts. Of course there are other options, but I see `string.Format`  as a very good one.

Comment: @Diego I don't when the string has { and } in it and `string.Format` makes you delimit them.

Comment: This is the problem, not any string works in this case, I need to get exactly this <<new {Area="Home"}>> otherwise will not work.

Comment: @LucianBumb Are you sure that's what you need?  because your code should give you that.  Maybe you actually need something else?

Comment: It is exactly what I need. I have this action running ok, with a if statement for the Area, and wanted to replace the big if/elseif with this string.format.

Comment: @LucianBumb, does `return RedirectToAction(model.Action, model.Controller,"new {Area=\"Home\"}");` work? Please try it.

Comment: @Diego - this is the error which I got trying to use<<"new {Area=\"Editor\"}" >>:http://localhost:55293/Emmo/Department/DepartmentPartial?Length=19 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Comment: Thats what I though. The error has nothing to do with how to build the string. That string is perfectly fine, but the argument you need to use is not a string

Comment: If you ment to use in your exemple something like :  var area =  '"'+ model.Area + '"'; is not working.

Comment: @LucianBumb, no, sorry. See it now.

Comment: Thank you for your help, that I already try it and not working. I will stay with may big IF statment :(.

Comment: If you show your if statemet that works, maybe we can completely understand your scenario